# xampp and mariadb - can I keep old data and queries

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mariadb

It's time to update my xampp to a newer version.
Now I see that xampp does not support mysql, but mariadb, instead.
What does it mean about my coding practice in php and mysql?
Do I need to change any table structure, any query syntax... what egzactly ?

Thanks.

Comment: No. It should be a fairly seamless transition

Comment: MariadDB is fork of MySQL, so as @Strawberry said, the transition should be fairly seamless. The function calls, table structure, queries, etc should still work as you have them now.